# Работа с xampp 3.2.2 при клике на любую ссылку перекидывает в корневую папку htdocs

Tags: drupal, localhost, xampp

Сайт на Drupal. Перенес сайт на локальный хостинг, при переносе на любой другой хостинг в том числе на denwer сайт работает нормально.

На xampp вначале не мог установить базу данных, поковырявшись в php.ini и my.ini решил проблему, но теперь возникла новая:

при клике на любую ссылку сайта, перекидывает в родительскую дерикторию (пути верные), и вместо страницы сайта открывается домашняя (родительская) страница XAMPP.

Пути нормальные, по прямой ссылке та же проблема.

Причем, если сайт устанавливать с нуля, то все нормально.

Если кто сталкивался, подскажите как решить проблему, в чем причина?

Comment: В шапке стоит `base href`? Какой вид имеют ссылки на сайте?

Comment: Внёс изменения в текст